# Why won't setTimeout() work?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am trying to simply make my function wait 3 seconds before running. It seems really straightforward but for some reason, I keep getting a:

> slideFunction is not defined

error in the console. It works if I just call the function without trying to use `setTimeout`. What is wrong here?

```
window.onclick = slideFunction;

setTimeout(slideFunction, 3000); { 
  document.getElementById('#img3').style.marginLeft = "100px";
}
```

Comment: What is `slideFunction`?

Comment: look at your syntax again.... it is not valid for creating a function. All you have is a call to setTimeout and a separate code block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire solution you are looking for:

```
function slideFunction(){
  document.getElementById('#img3').style.marginLeft = "100px";
}
window.onclick = slideFunction;

setTimeout(slideFunction, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1):

It works, but the function you are calling needs to be defined and to be a function. Example:

```js
function slideFunction(){
  document.getElementById('img3').style.marginLeft = "100px";
}

document.body.onclick = () => setTimeout(slideFunction, 3000);
```

```css
#img3 {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 100px;
  transition: margin-left .3s cubic-bezier(.4,0,.2,1);
}
body,html {height: 100%;margin: 0;}
```

```html
<div id="img3"></div>
<button onclick="document.location.reload(true)">Reload</button>
```

A few problems:

- `.getElementById('#img3')` is not correct. It's either `.getElementById('img3')` or `.querySelector('#img3')`, unless your element's `id` is really `#img3` i.e.: `<img id="#img123" src>`, in which case it is invalid:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

- `window.onclick` should be `document.body.onclick`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help everyone. I did manage to get it to work how I needed using

```
  function slideFunction(){
  document.getElementById('#img3').style.marginLeft = "100px";
  }

  document.body.onclick = () => setTimeout(slideFunction, 3000);
  }
```